# How to check is data in a numpy array follows a poisson distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wanted to know if an array follows poisson distribution I used Kolmogorov–Smirnov test `scipy.stats.kstest` but it returns p-value zero so I tested the following code and this also returns p-value of zero

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import( kstest, poisson)
mu=2
poissonDis = poisson.rvs(mu,size=10000)
kstest(poissonDis,'poisson', args=(1,), alternative = 'less',N=10000)
```

The output is

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.5972588823428846, pvalue=0.0)
```

Is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I should set the alternative hypothesis to greater this works

```
kstest(poissonDis,'poisson', args=(1,), alternative = 'greater',N=10000)
```